# Android how to get data from tabbed fragment when user presses hard back key?

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

I have three tabbed fragments, user can select data to fragments from date picker, problem is i want to save the selected data from the current fragment when user presses the hard back key.

How can i get current fragment data from fragments DayFragment, WeekFragment and MonthFragment, onBackPressed().

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
@Override
public void onActivityCreated(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);

    this.getView().setFocusableInTouchMode(true);
    this.getView().requestFocus();
    this.getView().setOnKeyListener(new OnKeyListener() {

        @Override
        public boolean onKey(View v, int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            if (event.getAction() == KeyEvent.ACTION_UP && keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) {

                // Write code here to save data

                return true;
            }
            return false;
        }
    });
```

Comment: i have to write this in fragment right? or in FragmentActivity ?

Comment: Yes. You have to write this on each fragment where you want to do something on back pressed event.